# how to read a data txt file and change a value under specific condition in python

Tags: python-2.7

I need to change a value with a specific condition in an output data file. An example of the output file is like below:

```
#comments
1 0 0.002799 296.404062 2.474652 1.769134
2 0 0.002799 293.540280 2.474652 1.769134
3 0 0.002799 296.404062 0.821247 4.107403
4 0 0.002799 290.676497 2.474652 1.769134
5 0 0.002799 287.812715 2.474652 1.769134
6 0 0.002799 296.404062 2.474652 1.769134
```

I need to change the second value(which is zero by default) to 1 if the last value in the line is smaller than 8, otherwise leave it zero. Could someone please help me with that?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your approach a came up with the following code:

```
with open('data.txt') as fin, open('outfile.txt','w') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        if line.startswith("#"):
            fout.write(line)
            continue
        fields = line.split()
        fields[1] = "0" if float(fields[-1]) < 8 else "1"
        fout.write(" ".join(fields) + "\n")
```

- If the `line` starts with `#`, it continues.
- Then it converts the line into an array of individual `fields`.
- If the last field is smaller than 8 (after conversion to `float`), the second field is set to "0" - and "1" if not.
- Finally, it joins the fields and writes them to the output file.

Comment: @AramA.: Oh, I edited the answer to keep the comments.

Comment: @ Falko : I got it ;) .Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(infile.chkpt) as fin,open('outfile.txt','w') as fout:
 for line in fin:
   #use line.split('\t'3) if the name of the field can contain spaces
   float,float,rest = line.split('\t'3)  
   #do something to change start and end here.
   #Note that `start` and `end` are strings, but they can easily be changed
   #using `int` or `float` builtins.
   fout.write('\t'.join((name,start,end,rest)))
```

Comment: @Falko I found something like this but could not figure it out how can I change it to make it work :(